# Can't dup NilClass on rails rake with assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to precompile my assets I get the following error.  This is the trace with the full output:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
TypeError: can't dup NilClass
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:38:in `dup'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:38:in `map'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:38:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/cache.rb:60:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/cache.rb:60:in `lookup_store'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:64:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/alex/Dev/livingrecipe/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:216:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

So unfortunately I can't figure out where the error is pointing to as none of the code is my stuff and mainly the trace consists of code from the default gems.  The one thing that I can see that I have added in there is the bootstrap gem, but the same thing happens even if I take that out.

Comment: I hope the DB access is not required? If it is then this is not going to work. When you are building the image the DB is not running at all. You cannot use `DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname`. If your code ignores and doesn't connect to DB then its a different issue but if it does then DB is not up while building the image. So fix that

Comment: the DB access isnt required, these are just dummy variables to make the code run, it was working before, but after updating my gems and project it broke and the error code doesnt really help track it down

Comment: I am assuming you are using [`redis-rails`](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails). Are you sure it is configured appropriately? Can you post your config/application and appropriate initializers?

Comment: So everything runs fine if I dont try to precompile the assets, it only crashes for the precompiling of the assets

Comment: This "/home/alex/Dev/livingrecipe/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'" is "[your] stuff" can you please post the configuration  in config/application and appropriate initializers as requested. It appears that your configuration is incorrect and that initialization fails because of it.

Comment: I have error like this when model was declared as **unloadable**. I remove this attribute and now all is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So not sure what the problem was, but i updated ruby, rails and all my gems and that got rid of the problem.  So thinking it was a compatibility issue with version mismatch somewhere

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have incorrect redis connection (or setup)

To debug it:

1. Debug redis connection with in rails console. [Using Redis from your application](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/tutorial/#using-redis-from-your-application)

   > > require 'rubygems'
   > > => false
   > > require 'redis'
   > > => true
   > > r = Redis.new
   > > => #<Redis client v2.2.1 connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0 (Redis v2.3.8)>
   > > r.ping
   > > => "PONG"
   > > r.set('foo','bar')
   > > => "OK"
   > > r.get('foo')
   > > => "bar"
2. Debug [RedisStore](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails)

   RedisStore.new("localhost:6379/0/cache", expires_in: 90.minutes)
3. If the command passed, set up this config for your app like it's described in [gem redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails)

   ## config/application.rb

   config.cache_store = :redis_store, "redis://localhost:6379/0/cache", { expires_in: 90.minutes }
4. Play with configuration a little to establish successful connection to redis (And don't forget about different environment configs in production!!!)
5. Commit changes, redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compile assets in the production environment, but you're also on your dev machine. Are you sure you've configured a production environment in all of your config files? Look in config/cable.yml and config/redis.yml if they exist.

Alternatively, a good way to compile assets in the development environment is:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

However, after doing this, Rails will use these compiled assets in development instead of your assets in app/assets. Eventually, you'll also want to run `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:clobber` or `rm -rf public/assets` to clear your development environment of these compiled assets.

Answer (score 0):

from the stack trace you submitted, it looks like you should check the value of

```
config.cache_store
```

it most probably empty:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/87eb1a26da0b1385af07a8347dcfd32998a614ee/railties/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb#L67